# Visual Studio Express 2010 (WP 7 SDK), no Targets available

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I just installed the Windows Phone 7.1 SDK + 7.1.1 Update on a freshly installed Windows 7. The installation of 7.1 SDK went fine, during applying the 7.1.1 update, my VM freezed and it took me some back and forth to get system booting again, using the MS recovery during startup. I then re-applied the 7.1.1 update.

Now, after starting VS Express and creating a new project, I'm unable to select a target for testing my application, the drop down menu is just empty (this happens to newly created projects and existing ones).

[image: screenshot with empty drop down menu]

Any hints what might be wrong?

Comment: Try to reinstal SDK. I think it will be the easiest way.

Comment: I noticed, that further updates were available via Windows update, so I went through all update cycles until no more updates showed up. After that, the targets are listed. But now, that whole VM crashes, when I try starting the emulator (okay, this seems to the way it is, "no VM inside VM"). After so many wasted hours, I hope at least to get Zune software working for being able to test directly on my device.